# Get the URL from mJSP page

Tags: jsp, url

I would grab the URL of the current JSP web page with its settings
example: index.jsp? param = 12

Have you any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get it from the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object which is in [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) available by `${pageContext.request}`. The part before the `?` is available by [`getRequestURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) method and the part after the `?` is available by [`getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) method. So, in a nutshell:

```
<p>Request URL: ${pageContext.request.requestURL}</p>
<p>Query string: ${pageContext.request.queryString}</p>
<p>Full URL: ${pageContext.request.requestURL}?${pageContext.request.queryString}</p>
```

If you want to do this using normal Java code, you'd better use a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for this.

```
String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
if (queryString != null) requestURL += "?" + queryString;
// ...
```

Comment: Warning: If you've forwarded to the jsp page using a RequestDispatcher, the abovementioned jsp code may not produce the URL you expected. It will produce the URL of the forwarded jsp page and not the URL that the user actually requested. I have [mentioned this to @BalusC before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624911/include-jsp-file-with-java/5624928#comment-6409455) and I'm still waiting for the a satisfactory workaround. For now, I'm including jsps instead of forwarding.

Comment: @Asaph: Wow, what an attitude. I must have overlooked this comment reply. It's set as a request attribute. For the name, check the value of constant `RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`. In the future, just press `Ask Question` if you have a question which you're looking an answer for.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to have an attitude about it. No hard feelings? So do you want to update your answer to use the request attribute instead of `${pageContext.request.requestURL}`?. It seems to me that this would better. No? Also, what if the request was forwarded multiple times? Will the request attribute still contain the URL that the user requested?

Comment: @Asaph: There is nothing which proves that the OP is doing a forward. If no forward is done, that attribute is not been set. I recall some related answers, you may find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663329/how-to-get-path-at-browser-in-jsp/3663408#3663408 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622461/how-to-know-when-the-request-is-forwarded-in-a-requestwrapper-object/5623974#5623974

Comment: Thanks. Those links were helpful. Again, I didn't mean to come off rude in my initial comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) Object, which you can access from your JSP in a scriplet (although that's not pretty).  It has many methods for getting the URL of the page, including the parameters.  Methods of interest will be:

```
 - getQueryString 
 - getRequestURI
 - getRequestURL
```

Have a play with them.