# How to get full URL in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, jsp-tags

How would I get the full URL of a JSP page.

For example the URL might be http://www.example.com/news.do/?language=nl&country=NL

If I do things like the following I always get news.jsp and not .do

`out.print(request.getServletPath());
out.print(request.getRequestURI());
out.print(request.getRequest());
out.print(request.getContextPath());`

Comment: request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the URL from mJSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097983/get-the-url-from-mjsp-page)

Answer (score 6):

You need to call [`request.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29):

> Reconstructs the URL the client used to make the request. The returned URL contains a protocol, server name, port number, and server path, but it does not include query string parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Given URL = http:/localhost:8080/sample/url.jsp?id1=something&id2=something&id3=something

```
request.getQueryString();
```

it returns id1=something&id2=something&id3=something

[See This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)

Comment: Thanks that helps get the query string. If I concat that with rickz comment I get what I want

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It may not be perfect solution. But it working solution.

```
String qs = request.getQueryString();
String foo = request.getRequestURL().toString()+"?"+qs;
```